# How to add and delete section in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to delete section from UITableView.

Here is my code for adding object to array :

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray new];
ClassName *section = [[ULPDPSection alloc] initWithTitle:@"Section-Title" rows:@[]];
[temp addObject:section];
self.sectionArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This is my numberOfRowsInSection code:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sectionArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rowsArray;//This is in ClassName

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        ClassName *section = [self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
        return section.rowsArray.count;
    }
}
```

This is my code to delete section:

```
if(image.count < 5)
            {
                NSUInteger index = [self indexForSection:@"Section-Title"];
                if(self.tableView.numberOfSections > index)
                {
                    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.sectionArray];
                    [temp removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                    [self.tableView endUpdates];

                }

            }
```

I'm getting crash message when trying to delete section: 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (5) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (5), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

Comment: this is because u r not updating the section array. From section array also u need to remove those section object. give your numberOfSection datasource implementation.

Comment: You're removing the object from a copy of your datasource array, but not saving the modification back to `self.sectionArray`. You should also update your model outside the `beginUpdates/endUpdates`.

Comment: You don't need the line:    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

just remove form the section array and reload the table